# ssh key connectivity issue outside of ~/.ssh dir

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

I have created the following structure under ~/.ssh

```
 ~/.ssh
      /keys
        /aws
          /prod
          /stage
```

and i put appropriate '.pem' private keys under these folders.
All directories under '~/.ssh' have 700 permission and ~/.ssh have 700 permissions also.

When I try to connect to remote servers with the private keys located under the tree structure using

```
ssh -l admin -i /home/user/.ssh/keys/aws/prod/prod_1.pem
```

it does not work, and i get password request.
When i put the same private key file under ~/.ssh it starts working.
Can someone please help to explain this behavior?

Comment: Use the `ssh -vvv` flag, it will tell you what is going wrong. Please post here the output.

Comment: A side note: you don't need as different key pair for each server that you connect to. It is sufficient to have one key for each machine that you connect from. Just put the public key onto every account@server that you want to connect to. (You could get away with only one key, but if you leave a laptop on a train, then you need to be able to disable the key).

Comment: `debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/dimitryz/.ssh/keys/amazon/prod/eu-west-1.pem
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
ubuntu@52.48.201.24's password:`